# opencart error like this in server

Tags: opencart

/ the below errors shows in opencart server hosting problem please find the output how to modify these error in opencart config file

fopen(/home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/cache/cache.language.1469448162): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/library/cache/file.php on line49Warning: flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/library/cache/file.php on line 51Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in/home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/library/cache/file.php on line 53Warning: fflush() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/library/cache/file.php on line55Warning: flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/library/cache/file.php on line 57Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in/home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/library/cache/file.php on line 59Warning: fopen(/home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/cache/cache.currency.1469448162): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in/home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/library/cache/file.php on line 49Warning: flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/library/cache/file.php on line51Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/library/cache/file.php on line 53Warning: fflush() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in/home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/library/cache/file.php on line 55Warning: flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/library/cache/file.php on line57Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/library/cache/file.php on line 59

Answer (score 0):

Open the websites files, go to `system > cache` and delete all the items in here, reload a page on the website and all your cache files should be repopulated with zero to no errors.